# Mercurial subrepos, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-subrepos

I've got a checkout of a project on my machine to which I've added subrepo. Works fine on that checkout, but when I clone the project in other location it doesn't clone subrepos. `.hgsub` is pushed to `default`.

Dir structure is

```
./projA/            ## - the main project directory
./projA/lib/projB/  ## - the sub-repo project directory
```

And `.hgsub`:

```
lib/projB = [hg]ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/username/projB
```

Now when I do `hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/username/projA` it makes no attempts whatsoever to fetch subrepo. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've kind of found solution. The problem was that `.hgsubstate` file was not generated. I've manually created one using hashes obtained via `hg --debug id -i lib/projB/` thus situation was like:

`.hgsubs`

```
lib/projB = [hg]ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/projB/
```

`.hgsubstate`

```
1e07729703d0e9447ae174a732bfd3e1cbdd96f4 lib/projB
```

Interestingly enough, after committing `.hgsubstate` it did get auto-regenerated.

After that change cloning works as expected, cloning recursively both main repo and subrepo:

```
hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/projA

destination directory: projA
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 13 changesets with 24 changes to 10 files
updating to branch default
cloning subrepo lib/projB from ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/user/projB
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 653 changesets with 3864 changes to 1899 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Read "Subrepos" topic from "Mercurial Kick Start Exercises", ["Remote Subrepositories"](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#remote-subrepositories) part

> Note that we clone the repository to the place where it should be, because just adding the entry in the `.hgsub` file will not do anything unless there is a repository and the given location.

Comment: Doesn't that refer to initially adding these subrepos?

Comment: @vartec - no, subrepo created as 1) cloning external repo to local 2) adding this local repo as subrepo with remote location. Reread linked topic fully, not only my quote